# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer. in android kitkat versions

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-4.4-kitkat

i am using REST api to connect with server on ssl https
the problm is on android kitkat devices. all device with kitkat version or 4.x.x are not making connection with server

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
```

on all above devices than 4.x.x working fine and making connection

Is there any solution for that. i have also tried OkHttp which is also not working in my cause.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem before, where my endpoint was using TLS 1.2 for encryption. If your endpoint is using `https` you could try change to `http` for unencrypted api call. If that is an option.

If you are only releasing your app on devices with `Google Play Services` you can use `ProviderInstaller` to provide support for TLS 1.2

```
fun installSecurityProvider() {
    try {
        ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(activity)
    } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) {
        handlePlayServicesError(e.connectionStatusCode)
    } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) {
        handleCriticalFailure()
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html

There was an issue opened on the okhttp git page which discussed this problem.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3098

If relying on play services is not an option then its possible to implement yourself.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372#issuecomment-244807676